# public webserver trying to query sqlserver on internal network with private IP

Tags: php, mysql, port

I am using php to send a query to an existing database to use existing login credentials for a webbased program to allow access to a members section page. My web server is public and has a public ip as well as a private ip. However, my sql server is sitting on the local lan and does not have a public ip. I am very new to php, but I feel I have a done a good job writing it. the code works amazingly when I hosted the site for internal use with a dummy database on my pc. I set up Apache on my pc to run the php code and set up a sql database for testing purposes. I could access the site and login and out from any other computer in the office, by typing in my 192.168.x.x into the web browser.

Now that the site is moved to the web server and I am linking to an active database on another server it doesnt want to work. I am pretty sure i dont have any coding erors causing this its a configuration issue. I am wondering what ports should be open where? and will existing DB users be able to query the DB from a remote private ip? I realize this may be a beginners question, but I have looked everywhere for days now and my brain is fried. I need a basic checklist of the main things to look for or set when establishing this type of connection.

Website is running on 192.168.1.1 with public ip of 173.72.173.x
SQL DB is running on 192.168.1.2
I log into the sql engine on the sql server with 'user' and 'password' so my config file i use:

```
$server = "192.168.1.2:3306";   // server to connect to.

$database = "myusers";      // the name of the database.

$db_user = "user";      // mysql username to access the database with.

$db_pass = "password";      // mysql password to access the database with.

$table = "dbo.users";       // the table that this script will set up and use.
```

And I call it into every file that need to query anything.

So are theses setting right? Or do I need to create another user on my sql engine to access the db from a remote host? and what about ports? sql server has 3306 opened, but that's it?

Comment: 'sql server' usually means 'microsoft sql server' in these parts, but mentioning port 3306 makes me thing you're using MySQL.

Comment: I set the site up using MySQL on port 3306 on my PC set up to run sql and php(apache) so i could test the site locally on company LAN. now the site is up, and I want to query the live existing DB on a sql server(MS server 2003 R2) running SSMS 2008R2 and listening on port 1433 and 1434. the web server is seperate. I am having issues going from a 'localhost' configuration to a 'remote host' configuration.

Comment: cont...I am currently trying an ODBC connection with PHP, but I am having no luck. I was able to get the ODBC DSN connected on the web server (also running MS server 2003R2) to the DB server and the connection tests successfully. but when my PHP code tries to connect I am not successful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL (you mentioned port 3306), you will most likely want to check the my.cnf configuration file on the MySQL server, and have it allow remote connections.

Just do a fast search for `bind-address          = 127.0.0.1` and comment it by putting a hash`#` in front of it and disable interface binding.

Since you did not specify the OS you are using, I can't know for sure whether it may be bound to a specific NIC or not. Try it yourself.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you just asked me to do. lol I am not a coder, I fix computers not write webpages. I did basic html about 10 years ago thats my experience level. I can read code and decipher it but thats about it. I did find out through the registry that MySQL instance is listening on port 1433 not 3306 but that gave no different outcome.
So you want me to find the my.cnf file and open it then fine a line for bind-address and comment it out??

Comment: @Daniel : Port 1433 is MS SQL Server not MySQL server.Update your question and tags.Refer to MSDN how to configure MS SQL Engine to allow remote connection.There is out-of-box configuration tool called MS SQL Management studio and MS SQL Surface configuration.